# Is Android showing app ads in share menu now?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, default-applications, ads, share-menu

Android is showing an Adobe app in the sharing menu and "Open with" dialog as if it's installed but will install it when I click on it.

> [image] [image]

Is this a new perk of advertising with Google Play? Is Adobe paying money to place an ad right in Android?

Comment: I have Android 8.1 LineageOS installed. Instant apps is turned off

Answer (score 64, accepted):

## Blame Microsoft not Google

- This behavior was reported in July this year. Microsoft was the culprit. See this XDA blog [Microsoft is abusing Android’s share sheet by inserting ads for its apps](https://www.xda-developers.com/microsoft-abusive-android-app-sharing-ads/) with [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/c9n2ll/microsofts_your_phone_companion_adds_a_onedrive/)
  and [Android Police](https://www.androidpolice.com/2019/07/08/microsoft-android-share-menu-ads/)
  links.

This clearly is a violation of monetisation and ads policy as stated in the blog. See [Google Play Content Policies](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy/)

- Your example shows Adobe products. I don't know if Adobe also started doing this or if it is a result of [Microsoft - Adobe collaboration](https://www.adobe.com/enterprise/microsoft-partnership.html)
- For reporting use [Report Inappropriate Apps](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/takedown) but I am not sure how far it would help.

Comment: Somewhat related [Is it allowed to offer incentives for 5 star ratings on the Google Play app store?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/219620/131553)

Comment: Of course, Google is allowed to push apps onto people.