# Who or what can trigger an app installation from Google Play Store?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, installation

I was more then sure that my actions in the Google Play Store (either mobile app or through website) are the only way to trigger installation of some app.

My phone was lying alone and dark for the last hour, I did nothing:

- around Google Play Store website on my PC,
- around any app or phone in general

in the last hour or so. But, when I have just unlocked it, I have found out that to my extreme surprise, it started installation of Microsoft Teams.

This is the first time in my 10+ years Android history that something like that has happened.

Who (or what) beside my can start installation of some app on one of my devices?

Comment: Are you talking about a new app or an update for an already installed app?

Comment: Any app that asks for [`REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES`](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/12085295?hl=en) permission //How do I find that out?  Install [PMX](https://github.com/mirfatif/PermissionManagerX) from GitHub or [Play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mirfatif.permissionmanagerx), give it permission for adb (read help) and in the search menu, [enable deep search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8huAw.png) and find out from app ops which app has this permission and disable /ignore that permission for that app

Comment: This app is developed by our valued contributor here [Irfan-Latif](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/218526/Irfan-Latif) 

Comment: Google Play Store allows compatible devices to receive an install instruction from ANY device which is linked to your account. If you visit a Play Store App Page, note that the Install button can have a pulldown, which lists linked devices. Any device there can initiate an install somewhere else. Say you have 2 phones, A & B, with A on the install page, BOTH A & B can be selected on the button and receive the install (or even forced to B alone - It can be disconcerting).

Comment: @Robert No, a brand new app, as I don't use mobile version of Microsoft Teams at all. Frankly saying, I don't use any Microsoft-related mobile app on my phone except for Microsoft Edge.

Comment: @wbogacz Thanks! I am aware of that. But still, in your scenario _any kind of input from user side must be done_, right? And as I mentioned -- I was doing nothing. No access to Google Play Store from _any device_. After an hour of letting my phone rest on the shelf, I picked it up and unlocked to check the time. It was completely accidental (and very surprising) to learn in the same time that _something_ has triggered installation of Microsoft Teams on my phone and that this process in around 25% in progress.

Comment: @beeshyams Can we consider a _completely separate app_ (Microsoft Teams) a package? Can we assume that some app can make use of `REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES` permission without any input from user side (see above comment)? Plus: I have never seen a request for enabling this permission for any app.

Comment: @trejder [The REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission may not be used to perform self updates, modifications, or the bundling of other APKs in the asset file unless for device management purposes. All updates or installing of packages must abide by Google Play’s Device and Network Abuse policy and must be initiated and driven by the user.](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9888170) //So on it's own it can't install BUT... Contd

Comment: [Microsoft is not above cheap stuff](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219845/131553)... If you can establish that's Microsoft is the culprit raise a Big stink.. Links are in the answer

Comment: Is it the device with broken screen problem? Wondering if the user initiated installation part is a part of whacky behavior?

Comment: @beeshyams No, this is a completely different device and case. Thanks for the information and link to "Report a Policy Violation". Since this was a one-time situation so far and since my account was not accessed by someone else (probably, see the comment below) I'd rather say that this was some kind of technical glitch. However, if the case repeats, I'll surely make use of "Report a Policy Violation". Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If it was a Google app instead of a Microsoft's one, I would bet it was triggered by Google itself, since they firmly believe they have ownsership of every single Android device ever made.

But in this case, someone may have accessed your Google account and installed it from the web store, which allows installing apps on all your devices, including Android TVs. Just in case, change your Google account password and [logout from all devices](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3067630?hl=en).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however you keep adding a guessing-answers which are prohibited here. This s probably why your answers gets downvoted. I think it is impossible for someone else to access my Google account as I have 2FA enabled and must manually (from the phone in question) approve each login attempt to my account using... Google app. Plus, I get an email from Google about each such login (even for each and every my own logins). Which is a bit frustrating, but useful. None of such things happened for this particular situation, so I assume that nobody has accessed my account this time.