# Disable web search in Microsoft Launcher

Tags: applications, launcher, ads

Recently, Microsoft launcher has started to give web search suggestions when I click on my home button and search for an app.

I only want to find apps, but in addition to installed app results the launcher now also gives internet search suggestions.

I want to disable that because I do not use it for that functionality. I guess this is MS's way of pushing Bing, but I still would like to disable it. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## It's Microsoft pushing ads for its apps, yet again

- Microsoft did this in July last year. See this XDA blog [Microsoft is abusing Android’s share sheet by inserting ads for its apps](https://www.xda-developers.com/microsoft-abusive-android-app-sharing-ads/) with [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/c9n2ll/microsofts_your_phone_companion_adds_a_onedrive/)
  and [Android Police](https://www.androidpolice.com/2019/07/08/microsoft-android-share-menu-ads/)
  links.
- Microsoft is back to it's dirty tricks again, this time by inserting  “Bing Search” option in the long-press context menu as reported in XDA in July, this year (annual schedule?) [Microsoft Outlook is inserting Bing Search into Android's long-press menu](https://www.xda-developers.com/microsoft-outlook-long-press-menu-bing-search/). Also by [Android Police](https://www.androidpolice.com/2020/07/13/microsoft-caught-sneaking-bing-search-onto-phones-with-the-outlook-app/)

[image]

## Solutions

- Find another launcher and uninstall Microsoft Launcher. Or [change search engine](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/229202/disable-bing-web-search-in-microsoft-launcher) in settings, if you want to continue using the launcher.
- Uninstall Microsoft Edge. XDA blog says that launcher triggers these ads *only* when Edge is installed (but some users have reported in comments that they don't have Edge installed but get this Bing search).
- Report to Play Store - use [Report Inappropriate Apps](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/takedown). Play Store has a very aggressive policy wherein developers are not allowed to even link their *own* apps.[This may cause app to be removed from Play Store](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=83429487&postcount=15855)

**Related (app violations)**

- [Is Android showing app ads in share menu now?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/219841/is-android-showing-app-ads-in-share-menu-now/219845#219845)
- [Is it allowed to offer incentives for 5 star ratings on the Google Play app store?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/219620/is-it-allowed-to-offer-incentives-for-5-star-ratings-on-the-google-play-app-stor)

Comment: It's a shame. I really like the launcher. Not too many bells and whistles. I do not have Edge installed so that does nor help  I guess I'll have to decide whether it's worth keeping...

Answer (score 0):

## The real solution

Just disable app's network access.

Go to settings - > apps - > find Microsoft launcher - > disable network access

It is indeed a really well made launcher.

Cheers